# wpf listbox resetting selectedIndex when containing grid resizes

Tags: wpf, listbox, selectedindex

I need a composite view consisting of a top part that can be hidden, a bottom part consisting of a navigation menu (listbox) on the left and a content area on the right.

One option in the listbox should make the top-part collapsed and other listoptions should show the top-part.

My idea was to split the screen in top- and bottom part using a grid with three rows (middle row for gridsplitter) and currently Im using codebehind for changing the height of the top grid.

The Problem is that when I set the Grid.Height-prop from codebehind, my ListBox.SelectedIndex is set from 1 to 0 ! Thing is that if I change order of the two menu-items, it works fine!

We are using Caliburn Micro, but I don't think that changes anything - the example could be implemented with INotifyPropertyChanged as well.

```
<UserControl x:Uid="UserControl_1" x:Class="VisionAir.Client.Gui.Common.Windows.Foo.Views.BarView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="300" Width="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Name="ResizableGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" Name="TopRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10" Name="SplitterRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="BottomRow"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="TopRowGrid" Background="Chartreuse" Visibility="{Binding ShowSearchView, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding ShowSearchView,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="10"/>
        <Grid Name="ListGrid" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName">
            </ListBox>

            <Grid Background="Chocolate" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Canvas Name="FooCanvas" Visibility="{Binding ShowSearchView, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"></Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace VisionAir.Client.Gui.Common.Windows.Foo.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BarView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BarView : UserControl
    {
        public BarView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FooCanvas.IsVisibleChanged += FooCanvas_IsVisibleChanged;
        }

        void FooCanvas_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;

            if (isVisible)
            {
                TopRow.Height = new GridLength(100);
                SplitterRow.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
            }
            else
            {
                TopRow.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                SplitterRow.Height = new GridLength(0);
            }
        }
    }
}


using System.Collections.Generic;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace VisionAir.Client.Gui.Common.Windows.Foo.ViewModels
{
    public class BarViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private List<Screen> _items = new List<Screen>();

        public BarViewModel()
        {
            Items.Add(new Screen() { DisplayName = "Hide" });
            Items.Add(new Screen() { DisplayName = "Show" });
        }
        public bool ShowSearchView { get { return SelectedIndex == 1; } }

        private int _selectedIndex;

        public List<Screen> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }

        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);

                _selectedIndex = value;

                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowSearchView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: Really sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I have seen that you added a few more words to your question... nothing really useful. In order for you to get the most out of this site, I advise you to take a quick read of the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help). For example, it appears that you *may* be trying to do something using an incorrect method, but as you didn't describe your problem, we can't show you a better method... you said *Im using codebehind for changing the height of the top grid*... you didn't say why. XAML should do this.

Comment: @Sheridan: Thx for helping. Create a VS-proj and copy/paste the code and I think you will easily see the effect. Codebehind was the easiest implementation. I would gladly convert it to a pure XAML-solution.